# Using forloops to generate dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

```
df1
           price         date          cost   variance
    0        152.45     2020-01-04     4         3
  ...
```

```
price = df1.loc[:, ['price', 'date']].set_index('date').dropna()

price
            price
date    
2020-01-04  152.45
```

Is there a way to perform the action above quickly for price and the other metrics? I tried:

```
metrics = ['price', 'cost', 'variance']
for x in metrics:
        globals().update({x:df1.loc[:, [x, 'date']].set_index('date').dropna()})
NameError: name 'price' is not defined
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you have a working vectorized version, why would you want to change that to a loop? Can you share a representative snippet of `df1`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler to use a `dict` that references your data frames than creating global variables (which is bad practice anyway)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""           price         date          cost   variance
    0        152.45     2020-01-04     4         3"""), sep="\s+")

metrics = ['price', 'cost', 'variance']

dfs = {m:df1.loc[:, [m, 'date']].set_index('date').dropna()
 for m in metrics}

for k in dfs.keys():
    print(f"DATAFRAME: {k}\n{dfs[k].to_string()}\n\n")
```

**output**

```
DATAFRAME: price
             price
date              
2020-01-04  152.45


DATAFRAME: cost
            cost
date            
2020-01-04     4


DATAFRAME: variance
            variance
date                
2020-01-04         3
```

Comment: This doesn't generate a dataframe that I can then reference elsewhere uniquely.

Comment: it generates 3 data frames corresponding contents of `metrics`. you can reference anywhere where `dfs` dict is in scope